# failing to create ALB ingress controller on amazon eks

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I am trying to create ALB ingress controller on amazon eks i am following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html documentation when i run kubectl apply -f alb-ingress-controller.yaml command i get below error. Please help me to fix this issue. i have referred many documentation but it is still failing to create ALB ingress controller. PF alb-ingress-controller.yaml file below

error:

The Deployment "alb-ingress-controller" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app.kubernetes.io/name":"alb-ingress-controller"}, MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable

```html
# Application Load Balancer (ALB) Ingress Controller Deployment Manifest.
# This manifest details sensible defaults for deploying an ALB Ingress Controller.
# GitHub: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
  name: alb-ingress-controller
  # Namespace the ALB Ingress Controller should run in. Does not impact which
  # namespaces it's able to resolve ingress resource for. For limiting ingress
  # namespace scope, see --watch-namespace.
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: alb-ingress-controller
          args:
            # Limit the namespace where this ALB Ingress Controller deployment will
            # resolve ingress resources. If left commented, all namespaces are used.
            # - --watch-namespace=your-k8s-namespace

            # Setting the ingress-class flag below ensures that only ingress resources with the
            # annotation kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb" are respected by the controller. You may
            # choose any class you'd like for this controller to respect.
            - --ingress-class=alb

            # REQUIRED
            # Name of your cluster. Used when naming resources created
            # by the ALB Ingress Controller, providing distinction between
            # clusters.
            - --cluster-name=Cluster-name

            # AWS VPC ID this ingress controller will use to create AWS resources.
            # If unspecified, it will be discovered from ec2metadata.
            - --aws-vpc-id=vpc-id

            # AWS region this ingress controller will operate in.
            # If unspecified, it will be discovered from ec2metadata.
            # List of regions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#vpc_region
            - --aws-region=ap-south-1

            # Enables logging on all outbound requests sent to the AWS API.
            # If logging is desired, set to true.
            # - --aws-api-debug
            # Maximum number of times to retry the aws calls.
            # defaults to 10.
            # - --aws-max-retries=10
          # env:
            # AWS key id for authenticating with the AWS API.
            # This is only here for examples. It's recommended you instead use
            # a project like kube2iam for granting access.
            #- name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
            #  value: KEYVALUE

            # AWS key secret for authenticating with the AWS API.
            # This is only here for examples. It's recommended you instead use
            # a project like kube2iam for granting access.
            #- name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            #  value: SECRETVALUE
          # Repository location of the ALB Ingress Controller.
          image: docker.io/amazon/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v1.1.3
      serviceAccountName: alb-ingress-controller
```

[image: i get above error after deleting old deployment and creating new one]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, I had to delete the old deployment then re apply.

```
kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
```

Lists all the deployments.

If you can see alb-ingress-controller:

```
kubectl -n [namespace] delete deploy alb-ingress-controller
```

Will delete the old deployment, then try again.

Comment: i deleted old deployment and started with new one i get above error. Please help i am new to kubernetes

Comment: i am using windows nodes  for cluster

Comment: I followed this tutorial , which use ALB 1.1.4, and has sucessfully set the cluster up.  https://www.learnaws.org/2019/12/16/running-eks-on-aws-fargate/.  Use kubectl logs -n kube-system $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | egrep -o "alb-ingress[a-zA-Z0-9-]+")   , assuming you are using namespace kube-system to deploy you ALBs to, it will output the POD logs. Add them to your question, there may be permission errors when calling the AWS API.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the ALB ingress controller issue by increassing the instance type to two t3.Xlarge Linux nodes. My cluster contains 2 Linux nodes and 1 windows nodes.Here is the documentation i referred.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-windows-workers.html
https://medium.com/faun/aws-eks-and-pods-sizing-per-node-considerations-964b08dcfad3